# Download of Ubuntu fails

Tags: downloads

I'm trying to download Ubuntu 12.04, I'm a newbie to Ubuntu, on a MS Windows XP machine using Opera (have also tried IE) but the download simply stops, with various %ages complete. I don't believe this is a problem with my machine as I've downloaded other things successfully both before and after failed attempts to download Ubuntu.

Any suggestions or are there mirror sites i might use?

Comment: What file are downloading?

Answer (score 3):

Use torrents to download the file. I've experienced several random pauses while downloading large files.

Or, you can use download managers (like DAP - Download Accelerator Plus, IDM - Internet Download Manager, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You may have more success downloading via BitTorrent. You'll need a BitTorrent client (I have had success with [uTorrent](http://download.cnet.com/uTorrent/3000-2196_4-10528327.html?tag=contentMain;contentBody;1d) in the past), and you can download the torrent file appropriate for your CPU [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads); you'll most likely want the `ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent` for a 64 bit system and `ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent` for 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Downloading with a browser is not a reliable way. I won't do a big download with a browser. As other answerer says, You can use torrent downloads.

[Download and Install utorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/downloads/). Then download one of the torrent files below. It should automatically opened by utorrent. If not, save the torrent file and use utorrent to open the saved `.torrent` file.

These link will download a Ubuntu with Live Session (a torrent file):

[Click this link to get Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop - 32bit version (torrent)](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent)

[Click this link to get Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop - 64bit version (torrent)](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)

If you want to use regular download, I recommend to use [Internet Download Manager](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/). It has a trial period of 30 days. Alternatively, you can use [Free download manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/download.htm).

Hope this helped!